# android TextView strange behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a simple textview in a linearlayout. The layout is for the items in a ListView. I am using the textView as a debugging tool: to track data. If I do getText() on the view everything is fine. But if I do setText I get an exception. So I put the two lines one after the other. setText still throw an exception. How is that possible? If the resource had a problem the getText should fail. But it prints fine.

code snippet:

```
 print(debuggingData.getText());//goes through fine
 debuggingData.setText("some text");//throws exception
```

error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1057)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4111)
    at com.mycompany.mygame.adapter.MyListAdapter.getView(MyListAdapter.java:115)
    at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2613)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1838)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:681)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1339)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1637)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2431)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
    at com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewAbove.onLayout(CustomViewAbove.java:476)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1669)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1527)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14482)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4469)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2151)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1970)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1183)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4863)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: in you real code, is it really "some text"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're trying to display an integer without converting it to a string first.
 `setText(0)` looks for a string with a resource ID of 0 and tries to load it, and if it can't, it throws an exception.

To avoid this problem, just convert your integer to a string with `Integer.toString()` :

```
debuggingData.setText(Integer.toString(...));
```

Comment: I am looking at the error trace, I can't see how you were able to tell. Where is the clue?

Comment: Well, I had this problem two or three times myself, so I knew what it was when I saw this exception. I think almost every developer has run into this at least once... this method should be renamed to something like `setTextFromResource()`.

Answer (score 1):

The error looks like you're really passing an integer to `setText` method. If that's the case, it would try to find the int in the resources strings, throwing the `Exception` if can't find it.